# Why do I need scope.property = scope.property() for expression to work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the below directive and in order for my `expressnum` function to evaluate in my template I need to use `scope.expressnum = scope.expressnum();`. It works but I don't know why. I thought maybe it might be something to do with binding or call order and I tried googling but can't seem to find anything, most likely because I don't really know what to look for. If someone could explain this to me and how I could possibly leave out `scope.expressnum = scope.expressnum();` and still be able to use it in my template I would greatly appreciate it.

```
app.directive('simplyIsolated', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            attnum: '@numone'
            ,bindnum: '=numtwo'
            ,expressnum: '&sq'
        }
        ,link: function (scope, elem, attr){
           scope.expressnum = scope.expressnum();

        }
        ,template:'<div><p> using "@" = {{attnum+attnum}}</p>'+
                        '<p>using "=" {{bindnum+bindnum}}</p>'+
                        '<p>using "&" {{expressnum(bindnum)}}</p><br/><p>{{y}}</p>'+
                '</div>'

    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `&` modifier in your scope definition binds to an expression rather than the value produced by executing that expression. Your statement simply executes the expression and stores the value.

Comment: but by putting the `expressnum(bindnum)` in an expression, does that not execute it?

Comment: @jonnieM - No. You'll find that `scope.expressnum` will contain a function that wraps the expression. Something like `function(){ return expressnum(bindnum); }`